# Why does counting to 2^24 execute quickly, but counting to 2^25 take much longer?

Tags: java, floating-point

I was fiddling around making infinite loops to test some other code/my understanding, and came across this strange behaviour. In the program below, counting from 0 to 2^24 takes <100ms on my machine, but counting to 2^25 takes orders of magnitude more time (at time of writing, it's still executing).

Why is this the case?

This was under Java 1.8.0_101, on a 64-bit copy of Windows 10.

TestClass.java

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addFloats((float) Math.pow(2.0, 24.0));
        addFloats((float) Math.pow(2.0, 25.0));
    }

    private static void addFloats(float number) {
        float f = 0.0f;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(true) {
            f += 1.0f;
            if (f >= number) {
                System.out.println(f);
                System.out.println(number + " took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " msecs");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried just running addFloats((float) Math.pow(2.0, 25.0));?

Comment: Because at some moment f+1.0 == f.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Ahh, that'll be it. I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: Why is your parameter a `Float`? Boxing isn't needed here and it will be unboxed every comparison (unless that's optimized somehow)

Comment: @1blustone whoops, fixed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596695/why-does-a-float-variable-stop-incrementing-at-16777216-in-c

Comment: here it's explained quite nicely

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039165/max-value-can-stored-in-java-float-with-two-digit-precision-2-digit-accuracy helped me understand why

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because `float`s have a minimum precision that can be represented, which decreased as the `float`'s value becomes larger. Somewhere between 2^24 and 2^25, adding one is no longer enough to change the value to the next largest representable number. At that point, every time through the loop, `f` just keeps the same value, since `f += 1.0f` no longer changes it.

If you change your loop to this:

```
while(true) {
    float newF = f + 1.0f;
    if(newF == f) System.out.println(newF);
    f += 1.0f;
    if (f >= number) {
        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(number + " took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " msecs");
        break;
    }
}
```

You can see this happening. It seems as though it stops increasing as soon as `f` reaches 2^24.

The output of the above code will be an endless number of "1.6777216E7" if you run it with 2^25.

You can test this value by using the [`Math.nextAfter` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter%28double,%20double%29), which tells you the next representable value. If you try running this code:

```
float value = (float)Math.pow(2.0, 24.0);
System.out.println(Math.nextAfter(value, Float.MAX_VALUE) - value);
```

you can see that the next representable value after 2^24 is 2^24 + 2.

For an excellent breakdown of why this happens, and why it starts mattering where it does, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12598343/2499035)

Comment: In other words, the second one doesn't just take longer -- it's an infinite loop!

Comment: When you are in the domain from 2^24 to 2^25 where the representable `float`s are exactly the even integers, when you do `f += 1.0f;`, the exact mathematical result would be an odd integer. Since this is exactly midway between the two nearest representable numbers, most implementation will pick the [doubly even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singly_and_doubly_even) one (i.e. the one divisible by four). If that is the case `16777216.0f + 1.0f` would be `16777216.0f` (no increment), while `16777218.0f + 1.0f` would be `16777220.0f` (actual increment is +2).